# Probability of red in traffic light cannot explain

Tags: probability, probability-theory

this is my question, every day going to work, I have  to pass through a traffic light, I have measured the time it takes on each signal

red= 15 seconds,
 yellow= 3 seconds,
 green = 45 seconds

But about 4 of 5 times or even 5 of 5 I get the red color, and I cannot explain it because according to probability I should be getting almost always green, I even get mad most of the times because of this, can someone explain it? Thanks.

Note: Maybe it is the time in which I pass it because it happens always between 4:50PM and 5:00 PM, but I've also looked at the minutes, and for each minute is the same result!

Comment: Obviously it hates you.  I've had similar experiences with certain signals, and that's the only logical conclusion I can find.  :) :)

Comment: Confirmation bias, perhaps?  You don't notice when you fly right through.

Comment: Or is synced in a bad way with the light before.

Comment: Yes I also think it hates me, or some invisible force! or an error in the matrix maybe? Also... it can be this (to get the red when I approach) or this other way: far away I can see the green fading just to eventually stop on red... And it happens only on this specific traffic light!! on the other 7 ones I cross, I always get random results as it should be!!!

Comment: You claim to have gathered some hard data ('I've also looked at the minutes, and for each minute is the same result!'). So why don't you show your data? This would allow us to discuss this question more seriously rather than getting shot down by additional data points you left out of your initial post.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because your have a model in mind of the situation does not match reality. It is not the case that you approach the traffic light without watching it, then look at it one instant and if it is green continue without watching again, and otherwise stop. That would be modelled by drawing one ball from a bag containing 5/7 of green balls and the rest red or yellow balls.

In reality, there is some point during your approach where you start seriously looking (in the sense that if the light is yellow or red there, you will start to slow down for stopping), but even if the light is green at that point, it may turn yellow before you actually reach the light, in which case too you will need to stop. All in all, the event that you will have to stop corresponds for the point where you first look at the light to all cases where the light is either yellow, red, but also to some final part of its green phase. Depending on how large that final part is (and it takes quite a bit of time to reach a light after you first see it), it might well be that the chances of slipping through while seeing only green are quite slim, even with the timings you gave.

Comment: But shouldn't the probability "shift" the result on my favor anyways?? I mean, these are still hard numbers...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that. In any case what I would do is mark the point where you first start caring about the light, and record what your odds are when you pass that point. If you still find the light is green much less than 5/7 of the time, then maybe there is somebody secretly observing you and turning the light red whenever you pass. But until you did the experiment I would not be inclined to such a hypotheses.

Answer (score 0):

Sure: the probability that you hit the red light is not independent. Presumably, before you reach that red light, you reach several red lights before it. These set you up so as to hit the red light when you get there.

Comment: The problem, is that it is the first traffic light...